# ExtJs change event wont fire on the change of the date time

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, dom-events, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have a handler in a controller which fires for some of the elements but not for date time elements, I have no idea how to make them work.

Here is the controller definition:

```
  this.control({

            'documentmailboxlist [itemId=filtersPanel] > container > combo': {
                change: this.filterInboxDocuments
            },
            'documentmailboxlist [itemId=filtersPanel] > panel > datefield': {
                change: this.filterInboxDocuments
            },
   .....
```

And here is the design:

```
    this.dockedItems = [
        {
            id: 'filtersPanel',
            xtype: 'container',
            itemId: 'filtersPanel',
            minWidth: 500,
            autoScroll: true,
            items: [

{
                        xtype: 'container',
                        dock: 'top',
                        layout: 'column',
                        defaults: {
                            margin: 7
                        },
                        autoScroll: true,
                        items: [
                            {
                                id: 'filterOrderDateFrom',
                                xtype: 'datefield',
                                fieldLabel: Translation.MailboxListDockedItemOrderDateFrom,
                                itemId: 'filterOrderDateFrom',
//                                flex: 1,
                                labelWidth: 110,
                                minWidth: 170,
//                                maxWidth: 180,
                                cls: 'filterInputField',
                                labelCls: 'webEdiInputLabelCenter'
                            },
                            {
                                id: 'filterOrderDateTo',
                                xtype: 'datefield',
                                fieldLabel: Translation.MailboxListDockedItemOrderDateTo,
                                itemId: 'filterOrderDateTo',
//                                flex: 1,
                                labelWidth: 110,
                                minWidth: 170,
//                                maxWidth: 180,
                                cls: 'filterInputField',
                                labelCls: 'webEdiInputLabelCenter'
                            },
                            {
                                id: 'filterDateFrom',
                                xtype: 'datefield',
                                fieldLabel: Translation.MailboxListDockedItemDateFrom,
                                itemId: 'filterDateFrom',
//                                flex: 1,
                                labelWidth: 65,
                                minWidth: 135,
//                                maxWidth: 145,
                                cls: 'filterInputField',
                                labelCls: 'webEdiInputLabelCenter'
                            },
                            {
                                id: 'filterDateTo',
                                xtype: 'datefield',
                                fieldLabel: Translation.MailboxListDockedItemDateTo,
                                itemId: 'filterDateTo',
//                                flex: 1,
                                labelWidth: 65,
                                minWidth: 135,
//                                maxWidth: 145,
                                cls: 'filterInputField',
                                labelCls: 'webEdiInputLabelCenter'
                            }]
                    }
```

All events fire correctly except the `filterOrderDateFrom` and `filterOrderDateTo`. Anyone any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You're really convoluting your selectors by trying to make them trail down that exact path.    If you change your wrapping containers at all, you'll have to go back and change your selectors too, and that can be a huge headache.

In your current code, it looks like you are trying to go through a `panel` but your view uses a `container`.  Try simplifying your selectors:

```
this.control({
    'documentmailboxlist #filtersPanel datefield' : {...}
})
```

If you need more exact selectors, give the fields `itemId`s and use that:

```
this.control({
    'documentmailboxlist #filtersPanel #myDate' : {...}
})
```

Comment: Ye that one doues not work at all by me. But thank zou fot the panel tip. i changed it to panel and it worked.